# Check whether the ear got deployed in jboss using batch file

Tags: batch-file, deployment, jboss7.x, izpack

I have created a installer which creates a shortcut which servers the purpose of starting the jboss service and launching the application via a browser.

For achieving this i deployed Jboss 7.1 as a service and have a batch file which starts the jboss service
using command **sc start SERVICE_NAME** and the next activity it should do launch the application by opening a internet explorer with a specified url. like e.g

**START iexplore urloftheapplication **

The problem is that i only want o launch ie with the url only when the **application(.ear) gets deployed not when the jboss service is started** or in other words when in the JBOSS deployments folder has a **.deployed file** indicating that the application is well deployed

How to achieve this? Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be included in your batch deployment process. Adapt as needed

```
    ...
    set "JBOSS_DEPLOYMENT_DIR=C:\Wherever\JBOSS\Deployment\Is"
    set "deployedAPP=nameOfAppFile"

:checkIfDeployed
    rem test for existence of file
    if exist "%JBOSS_DEPLOYMENT_DIR%\%deployedAPP%.deployed" (
        goto appDeployed
    )

    if exist "%JBOSS_DEPLOYMENT_DIR%\%deployedAPP%.failed" (
        goto deployFailed
    )

    rem file does not exist, wait for 5 seconds
    ping -n 6 -w 1 localhost >nul

    rem test again
    goto checkIfDeployed

:appDeployed
    rem here, the app is deployed
    ...
    ...
    goto endDeploy

:deployFailed
    rem here, the deployment failed
    ...
    ...
    goto endDeploy


:endDeploy
    rem ....
```